# Selecting data In Excel as a group between certain cells and dividing each by group value to find percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, grouping

**Background:** I have a table describing a imaginary formulation. The main ingredients/materials are Flavour A, B, and Emulsion and a gel mix. These are highlighted in bold in the table (see attached image).

- Flavour A makes up `54%` of the total formulation and is made up of sub-components: water, Benzoic acid, HCl and Sodium
- Flavour B makes up `10%` of the  formulation and is not made up on any sub components i.e. is `100%.`
- The Emulsion makes up `19%` of the formulation consisting of Water, Oil, Nacl and Ester and a Blue Dye
- The Gel mix makes up the final `17%` of the formulation and consists of Gel A, B, a gum texture and purified water.

The attached images also shows the percentage of each sub component making up each ingredient.

[image]

Although this is a made up example the data I am provided with is presented in the same way.

**Problem:** I wish to create a new column D that, looking at this data, can automatically calculates the percentage of each sub ingredient as a percentage of the Main ingredients. For example the Oil/Lipid is `63%` of the emulsion which is 19% of the total formulation. `(0.63*0.19)*100 = 11.97` as the desired output in column D. Similarly a hyphen in column C indicates the ingredient is 100% and should return a value equal to the percentage of the entire formulation e.g `54%` returns `54`. The total of each of these values will not add up to 100 since the output will contain values for the original material and its constituent sub components.

The way the data is formatted is however what makes this quite challenging.

**What I have tried so far:**
Firstly I cannot offer any existing code, simply because I don't know how to go about this. All I can think of so far is that because when a Hyphen is present in column C, this identifies the start of the sub component list and the next hyphen will identify the end. Each value between these two then need to be independently divided by the cell adjacent to the hyphen In column B and multiplied by 100 (Note if necessary the hyphen can be changed to 1.0 or 100%). I'm wondering if the data can be filtered in some way (FILTERXML?) but I'm not sure.

The desired outcome column in the attached image show the the values I am trying to achieve in column D. These were achieved by manually calculating each value however that is what I am trying to avoid here. (apologies if there are any mistakes)

Any help is really appreciated (even if some elaborate work around). Equally however if you don't think this is possible let me know.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this is to add a formula within a helper column which checks whether a cell in Column B is empty and if it is, takes the value from above, and if it is not, takes the value from Column B, e.g. 54%. So in Column E add the following:

```
=IF(B3="", E2, B3)
```

And then in Column D add the following which uses your helper column to get your desired result:

```
=IF(C3="-", B3, E3*C3)
```

This looks to see if there is a "-" in column C and if there is, takes the total value from column B, and if there is not, multiplies the respective percentages together.

Comment: Apologise for ignoring this answer, In my mind I didn't think it would work but having tried it its actually a really simple solution to my Problem and has solved a subsequent issue I've been having.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula. Paste to D3 and copy down.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B3<>""),$B:$B)*IF(ISNUMBER($C3),$C3/100,1)
```

The formula works on the assumption that cells in column B are vertically merged and that column C has a non-numeric character in it (such as a hyphen) to identify the caption row of each segment.

Comment: Sure, post a link to your new question here and I'll be notified..

Comment: Hey again, I've actually deleted that question because I think its flawed. I'm going to try to return to this answer because it works well but see if I can get it to work the formula that inputs the data.